# Python to work with csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there any direct way to convert a column of the csv file to a row and convert it into a matrix of values..
like this

```
Userid Placeid rating
e1      100      2
e2      101      3
e3      100      1
e4      102      4
```

has to be converted to

```
        100     101    102
e1       2       na     na
e2       na      3      na
e3       1       na     na
e4      na       na      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

data = """
Userid Placeid rating
e1      100      2
e2      101      3
e3      100      1
e4      102      4 
"""

df_data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df = pd.pivot_table(df_data, index=['Userid'], columns=['Placeid'], values='rating')
```

which will give you

```
Placeid  100  101  102
Userid                
e1       2.0  NaN  NaN
e2       NaN  3.0  NaN
e3       1.0  NaN  NaN
e4       NaN  NaN  4.0
```

---

The reason why pandas will convert the values to `float` is explained [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @displayname Will you be able to suggest some way so that this change gets reflected in the actual csv file or a new csv file gets created with this change?

Comment: @Ankita Well, you can just save it as a CSV file: `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` :) (see [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html))